# Decoding 32bit unsigned int in 4 unsigned char in Perl

Tags: perl, pack

I have to write in a binary file these hex values:

```
my $erase_start = 0x00010000;
my $erase_size  = 0x00008000;
```

And this is the expected result

[image]

Using

```
print WRITEHANDLE sprintf('%08X', $erase_start);
print WRITEHANDLE sprintf('%08X', $erase_size);
```

I obtain

[image]

I was taking a look to pack/unpack capabilities, but I am not a Perl Guru.

Comment: `printf HANDLE ...` is a shorter way to express `print HANDLE sprinf ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to write those 32-bit unsigned ints to a binary file. So I guess you want something like this:

```
open my $fh, ">", "file.dta" or die;
binmode($fh);
print $fh pack("N*", 0x00010000, 0x00008000);   #one or more u32 values
close($fh);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kjetil, I still need your help; I want to store the CRC16 at the end of the file; checksum is correct, but my attempt:
`print WRITEHANDLE pack("n",$ctx->hexdigest); #NOT OK!!! `
does not work as expected (it wites two 0x00 bytes instead of the expected checksum). Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf %X` produces hex, which is a *text* representation of a number. That's not what you want.

You want to output the numbers as big-endian 32-bit integers. To that end, you can use

```perl
pack('N*', $erase_start, $erase_size)
```

or

```perl
pack('L>*', $erase_start, $erase_size)
```

You might be interested in [Formats for Packing and Unpacking Numbers](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11111036).